# JQuery Overflowed Div, animate shifting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not sure how to word this, so a little jsfiddle work:

http://jsfiddle.net/UwEe2/

That's the basic idea for what I need done, except that I am in need of the image to be centered (so that the very center, horizontally and vertically, [of this image](http://nyquil.org/uploads/IndianHeadTestPattern16x9.png), appears in the little 250x250 window and is capable of being scrolled in all four directions to the edges of the image.

What I have, which would work if I would get the exact height and width of the image halved, http://jsfiddle.net/UwEe2/599/, which uses a second div inside the first with `style="position:relative; top:-330px; left:-330px;"`, which shifts the image more to where I need it, but disallows the scrolling of the image left and up any further than the initial screen.

Hopefully this makes sense...I'm rather at a loss right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is set the initial `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` to the size of the image minus the container divided by two.

```
$('#container').scrollTop(($('#container img').height()-$('#container').height())/2).scrollLeft(($('#container img').width()-$('#container').width())/2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UwEe2/600/